# Return NaN while adding the element of array

Tags: javascript

Given array is arr = [1,3,4,5]
My code is

```
var sum =0; 
for(var i=0;i<=arr.length.i++){
     sum += arr[i];
}
console.log("Sum of array is "+sum);
```

Output:
Instead of print

> sum of array is :13

it's printing

> Sum of array is :NaN

i am new in javascript so please help me by explaining the output why its coming NaN

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Error in

```
i<=arr.length
```

use

```
i<arr.length
```

because array indexed from 0 to length-1, and when `i==arr.length`, then `arr[i]===undefined`, so `number + undefined` is given `NaN`.

Also, you have a typo here `i<=arr.length.i++`, instead last `.` should be `;`

So finish sample

```js
var arr = [1,3,4,5];
var sum =0; 
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
     sum += arr[i];
}
console.log("Sum of array is "+sum);
document.write("Sum of array is "+sum);
```

Also for summing element you can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function in next way

```js
var arr = [1,3,4,5];
var sum =arr.reduce(function(a,b){return a+b;}); 
console.log("Sum of array is "+sum);
document.write("Sum of array is "+sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

Two issues with `i<=arr.length.i++`:

- Using `<=` means the loop will continue for one more iteration after the end of the array is reached. Use `<` instead.
- `.i++`, here the `.` should be a semicolon `;`

Fixed:

```
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
```